# Integrating Paypal payment APIs on server side

Tags: mysql, api, paypal, integration, backend

I have a Java Server providing web services to my frone end web application. One of functionality of our web application is to accept recurring payments from our customer and also pay to the sales agents using"pay me" option.

I want my backend Java server to talk to PAypal apis directly and deal with all payments.
For ex: When sales agent says "pay me", I will capture his/her paypal account id and store in my database. Then backend process will kick in and does the payment to the agent using paypal apis.

Is this possible with paypal APis?

I have seen every where that paypal integration can onyl happen via web

Answer (score 0):

As long as your system can carry out an API operation from the backend, there isn't any reason that it shouldn't work.  I have a cron job set up that runs every morning and performs an API call.